# What is the exact use of latestDateCovered in GetUpdated() soap call?

Tags: soap-api

We are using getUpdated() soap API call for getting the updated results. From below link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getupdated_getupdatedresult.htm

A value here indicates that, for safety, you should use this value for the startDate of your next call to capture the changes that started after this date but did not complete before the endDate and were, therefore, not returned in the previous call.

But we are using endDate as next start Date.
Is there any problem if we are using endDate as next startDate?.
What exactly the difference between latestDateCovered and endDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is subtle. endDate possibly includes records that were still "in flight" at the time of the API call, meaning were not returned because they were not yet fully committed, while lastCoveredDate includes records that are definitely committed. If you use endDate, you may miss records, although rarely, depending on your database activity at the time between your API calls.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have used latestDateCovered as startDate for next cycle. There is possibility that it would return duplicate data as some time latestDateCovered will returning the same DateTime. As per below link 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334799&type=1&mode=1 the latestDateCovered is updated with long running transaction. Is there any way we can avoid duplicate data? Or we should handle in our code the duplicate results?

Comment: @veerabhadra Yes, you should be using latestDateCovered, and yes, you may have to deal with redundant updates. You should use the Salesforce ID to update records in your external database (e.g. by using it as a primary key) to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox.